# Libgdx can't read .ttf file when running Android configuration

Tags: java, libgdx, android

Firstly, I am aware that a similar [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/why-cant-i-read-ttf-file-when-running-android-configuration) was asked some time ago that went unanswered. Currently, it has multiple upvotes but no answer.

The error

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: data/font/font1.ttf (Internal)
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: font/font1.ttf
```

occurs when I use the class `FreeTypeFontGenerator` provided by Libgdx as a extension to use freetype fonts[(link)](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype). This is the line in my project that caused error:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font/font1.ttf"));
```

I can be fairly certain that my path to the .ttf is correct, as the desktop configuration runs perfectly, showing the font as desired.

My guess: I didn't include the `freetype` extension when creating this libgdx project. When following the tutorial to include it (that is, adding the `freetype` dependencies in build.gradle), something somehow went wrong. But even this is not convincing enough.

`build.gradle`:

```
project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"



    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me, even though not the same as [the similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/why-cant-i-read-ttf-file-when-running-android-configuration).

My actually font filename in the `font` folder is `font1.ttf`. After changing it to `font.ttf`, the problem resolved itself. I don't understand why it worked, as I think it is okay to include numbers and uppercase in a file name.